# Best approach to predict how far into process a subject will progress?

Tags: regression, anova, predictive-models, marketing

I have a seven step process that users can complete but can stop at any time - basically a marketing funnel. At each point along the funnel I am collecting more data.

I want to be able to predict how far into the the funnel a subject with x set of attributes will go.

Is linear regression a valid approach where my y variable is the final step the person completed? Each step is not necessarily equal as some steps ask for more personal information that other steps.

I've done k-means clustering on the last step to understand the groups that exist for the final step. My next step is to do k-means clustering across steps, excluding my dependent variable and doing a confusion matrix afterwards to see if the groups align to the stages of the funnel.

An ANOVA test would tell me if there are differences among the groups based upon their completion step - but I don't think that would give me predictive capabilities if there were differences. True?

Other ideas for generating a predictive model and assumption issues you see?

I'd appreciate any code examples in R, if possible.

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Linear regression is certainly the first thing to try, although you rightly point out that it may be hampered by how $Y$ isn't on an interval scale. Ordinal regression exists to correct this problem, so that's a logical thing to try, too. Use cross-validation to find the most predictively accurate model of the models that you'd like to consider and go with that one.

$k$-means clustering and ANOVA seem of little value to you here. There's no reason to think that the clusters produced by $k$-means would be predictively useful, and ANOVA is really just a significance test, which has no relevance to prediction, as you've guessed.